# A fixed point theorem for the topological $2$-disc

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fixed-point-theorems

> If there is a continuous function from the topological $2$-disc $D$ to itself such that it is identity map on boundary, then there exists a fixed point in the $D$'s interior?

Notice that this map can be injective or not.

Comment: Consider a map which moves every point some distance to the right.

Comment: Is this identity map on boundary?

Comment: I meant every interior point... you can set such a continuous map up so that it is identity on the boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this explicitly is to pass from the interior of the disk to the upper half plane, for example using the map $f(z) = i \frac{1+z}{1-z}$  Then let $g$ be the map of the upper half plane that scales $y$ by some amount without changing $x$, so $g(x+iy) = x+icy$ for some $c > 0$.  $f^{-1}gf$ will then move every point in the interior, but without changing the behavior as you limit to the boundary.